# What is the difference between "Information Regarding Entry and Exit" and "travel history" for the U.S. Customs and Border Protection?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, history

I see:

- "Travel history": https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-results
- "Information Regarding Entry and Exit": https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records

What is the difference between the information contained in "Information Regarding Entry and Exit" and "travel history" for the [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Customs_and_Border_Protection)?

Comment: I-94 history gives you bare bones info of your entry and exit information. The CBP FOIA records will include any interaction with immigration like detention, interviews, and what they recorded about the interactions.

Comment: @AugustineofHippo thanks you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Comment: @AugustineofHippo, I made a FOIA request for my own travel records earlier this year and got bare bones entry and exit information. It is quite possible I could have gotten more if I'd known what to ask for, but I think a primary difference is that US citizens and LPRs don't have I-94 records so FOIA is the only route to get travel records for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same experience as [Dennis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/38879/dennis): I made an [FOIA request](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/22456/164) for my own travel records earlier this year for entries/exits, and got bare bones entry and exit information.

FOIA screenshot:

[image]

I-94 screenshot:

[image]

I-94 contains fewer records: it only contains entries/exits for 1 passport, at least for me. My I-94 did contain my entries/exits as an LPR.

Comment: Was the travel history complete in your case or were there any gaps?

Comment: @JonathanReez looks complete on FOIA. Only for 1 passport on I-94 but otherwise I believe is complete (I didn't have any land crossing via the passport though, so unsure if i-94 has land entries).

Comment: In my case my travel history at the I-94 website had no records for travel after I became a LPR and now returns "No record found for traveller". I thought it might be because my travel was now being associated with my green card rather than my passport but the FOIA records list my passport as the travel document even for entries where I'm pretty sure I didn't show it to anyone. I know not why this is.